# wp_get_recent_posts() exclude specific post by id

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

I am trying to get the two most recent post but however i want to exclude a specific post by its id[365]. Can anyone help me with it? here's my code.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' , 'post__not_in' => array( '365' ) );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
 <?php foreach($recent_posts as $post):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $post['guid']?>"><p><?php echo $post['post_title'];?></p></a>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to replace your code by below mentioned code, you will get your desired result :

```
<?php $my_args = array('post_type' => 'post' , 'numberposts' => '2' , 'exclude' => '365' );
$my_recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $my_args );?>
 <?php foreach($my_recent_posts as $my_post):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $my_post['guid']?>"><p><?php echo $my_post['post_title'];?></p></a>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [read the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) for that function again. You have an `exclude` parameter available:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' , 'exclude' => 365 );
```

Answer (score 0):

**wp_get_recent_posts** Does not support `post__not_in` argument you will need to use `exclude`

Reference link for [wp_get_recent_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' , 'exclude' => '365' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach($recent_posts as $post){ 
?>
     <a href="<?php echo $post['guid']; ?>">
        <p><?php echo $post['post_title']; ?></p>
     </a>
 <?php } ?>
```